# Multiple value array

Tags: arrays, jscript

I am new to jScript and have written this code [which works perfectly]. Its purpose is to test that the term for the amount of loan is not exceeded. Can the process be consolidated into one array where you pass the loan amount which returns the term based on the range i.e. 6000 to 7000 = 96

```
function TestMaxTerm()
{
     var LnAmt = 14000 //Testing Purposes
        var Term = 0 //Testing Purposes

        if (LnAmt > 0 && LnAmt <= 1000){Term = 0;}
        if (LnAmt > 1000 && LnAmt <= 2000){Term = 1;}
        if (LnAmt > 2000 && LnAmt <= 3000){Term = 2;}
        if (LnAmt > 3000 && LnAmt <= 4000){Term = 3;}
        if (LnAmt > 4000 && LnAmt <= 5000){Term = 4;}
        if (LnAmt > 5000 && LnAmt <= 6000){Term = 5;}
        if (LnAmt > 6000 && LnAmt <= 7000){Term = 6;}
        if (LnAmt > 7000 && LnAmt <= 8000){Term = 7;}
        if (LnAmt > 8000 && LnAmt <= 9000){Term = 8;}
        if (LnAmt > 9000 && LnAmt <= 10000){Term = 9;}
        if (LnAmt > 10000 && LnAmt <= 11000){Term = 10;}
        if (LnAmt > 11000 && LnAmt <= 12000){Term = 11;}
        if (LnAmt > 11000){Term = 12;}


        //Obtain Maximum Term for Loan Amount
        var MaxTerm = new Array();
        MaxTerm[0] = 24; MaxTerm[1]=36; MaxTerm[2] = 48; MaxTerm[3] = 60;
        MaxTerm[5] = 72; MaxTerm[5]=84; MaxTerm[6] = 96; MaxTerm[7] = 108;
        MaxTerm[8] = 120; MaxTerm[9]=132; MaxTerm[10] = 164; MaxTerm[11] = 176;
        MaxTerm[12] = 420;


        var text = MaxTerm[Term];
        alert(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put all of the data into a 2D array and loop through the array to find your answer.
Here's some sample code which you can tweak for your JScript implementation.  Your last entry could go from 12000 to your max loan amount or Number.MAX_VALUE

```
var loanAmt = 2200; 
var answer = -1;

var myData =
[
    [0, 1000, 24],
    [1000, 2000, 36],
    [2000, 3000, 48],
    [3000, 4000, 60]
];

for (var x=0; x < myData.length; x++) {

    if ( (loanAmt > myData[x][0]) && (loanAmt <= myData[x][1]) ) {
        answer = myData[x][2];
        break;
    } 
}
```

alert(answer);

Comment: Thanks very much Bob your prompt response was very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As the terms are multiples of 12 and the grouping is based on 1000, the term can be computed:

```
% function f(amt) {return 12 * (2 + Math.floor(amt / 1000));}
undefined
% f(6500)
96
% f(3999)
60
% f(4000)
72
%

On second thought:

% function g(amt) {return 24 + 12 * Math.floor((amt - 1) / 1000);}
undefined
% g(1)
24
% g(999)
24
% g(1000)
24
% g(1001)
36
% g(6000)
84
% g(6001)
96
% g(6999)
96
% g(7000)
96
% g(7001)
108
%
```